# Using decorative loaf pans

Tags: baking, quickbread

I bought a really nice loaf pan based on the picture on a magazine cover.  It is a Bundt harvest loaf pan and the bottom is molded into the shape of fallen leaves, a pumpkin, whatever.  But that is the bottom.  But it becomes the top for serving purposes, right?  But the top of the loaf is still going to rise into a traditional loaf which is mounded.  So really, how useful is this pan when it seems like I am going to have to trim away a large portion (the best part too) so that the load is flat.  Does anyone have any experience with this type of pan.

Answer (score 1):

If you bake a slightly undersized loaf for the pan, you won't have to trim much off, just enough for it to sit flat - maybe even that wouldn't be needed.

But I'd regard that as a first step - do that once or twice to get the quantity, then bake with a baking sheet over the top, so that the loaf expands against a flat surface.

With a yeast bread I'd probably take off the baking sheet lid half way through, but with a quickbread you'd have to wait a little longer. If the dough isn't too liquid, you could also try loading the dough into the pan, putting the baking sheet on top, then flipping the whole thing over. Again you could remove the upper piece for the end of cooking.

I've also seen very similar pans used to cook other things than bread, that don't rise, such as meatloaf, but in general they work best for things that don't stick too much as they can't be lined and are awkward to grease properly..